# Grails Automated Build with TFS for IBM websphere server

Tags: grails, websphere, tfsbuild

Has anyone used TFS for automated build for grails app.Do we need to write ant build.xml or can we use Gant script for TFS?
How does the build automation work with TFS for Grails App?
I need to automate build for websphere server using TFSBuild

Comment: There exists `gradle` and `maven` way to build and assembly grails project. And possibly (but I'm not sure) `ant` too.
If TFS supports one of these, then you can try.
Why are you can't use default `grails clean && grails war` way?
Do TFS supports to run any console command?

Comment: I think TFS supports only build.xml thats called from Build Agent.I am not able to use default grails command as my team uses TFSBuild for rest of the other projects.Somehow I have to automate build using TFS.

Comment: Do you able to write some plugin to TFS? )
In plugin you may use any tools/libs to build.
That is for very old version of grails.
Please look `http://grails.org/doc/1.1/guide/4.%20The%20Command%20Line.html` maybe it helps somehow.

Comment: And for the latest grails version `http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html`